# How to save using array? codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently doing a airline reservation. I have field no. of passengers, what ever you have entered it, it will be use to determine how many tickets will be given and I also make it session so that I can use it in my another page. After selecting a flight that is available

Example: I put 2 in no of passengers. then there will be a 2 tickets. The fields that I've for tickets are: pass_type(Adult, senior, child), name, birthday and gender

NOTE: I also tried to use the explode(); - explode means if it found a ,/-(first delimiter) it will separate it right? In my case there's no comma, / or dash

When I tried to var_dump this is the result:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "Senior Citizen"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "Senior Citizen"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "X"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "X"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "XX"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "XX"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "XXX"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "XXX"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "1995-10-05"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "1995-10-05"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Male"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Male"
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function tickp() 
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass_type[]', 'Traveler', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('t_fname[]', 'First Name', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('t_mname[]', 'Middle Name', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('t_lname[]', 'Last Name', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('t_bday[]', 'Birthday', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('t_gender[]', 'Gender', 'required|trim');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->selected_flight();

        }
        else
        {
            $traveler_info = array(
                $pass_type = $_POST['pass_type'],
                $t_fname = $_POST['t_fname'],
                $t_mname = $_POST['t_mname'],
                $t_lname = $_POST['t_lname'],
                $t_bday = $_POST['t_bday'],
                $t_gender = $_POST['t_gender'],
                );


            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($traveler_info);die;

            echo "</pre>";

            $this->CrudModel->insert('ticket',$traveler_info);
        }

    }
```

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="<?= base_url() . 'User/tickp' ?>">
                      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $this->session->userdata('pass_num'); $i++) { ?>
                  <!-- Code insert end-->
                          <div class="divTableRow">
                              <!-- Code replace-->
                              <div class="divTableCell">
                              <?= validation_errors();?>
                                  Traveler<br> 
                                  <select name="pass_type[]" id="pass_type[]">
                                      <option value="---" selected disabled>---</option>
                                      <option value="Senior Citizen">Senior Citizen</option>
                                      <option value="Adult">Adult</option>
                                      <option value="Child">Child</option>
                                  </select>
                              </div>
                              <div class="divTableCell">First Name<br> <input type="text" name="t_fname[]" id="t_fname[]"></div>
                              <div class="divTableCell">Middle Name <br> <input type="text" name="t_mname[]" id="t_mname[]"></div>
                              <div class="divTableCell">Last Name <br> <input type="text" name="t_lname[]" id="t_lname[]"></div>
                              <div class="divTableCell">
                                  Date of Birth <br>
                                  <input type="date" name="t_bday[]" id="t_bday[]">
                              </div>
                              <div class="divTableCell">
                                  Gender<br>
                                  <select id="t_gender[]" name="t_gender[]">
                              <!-- Code replace end-->
                                      <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                      <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                  </select>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                  <!-- Code insert-->

                      <?php } ?>
                      <button type="submit" class="booksend">BOOK</button>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Do you have database? Have you designed tables and relations already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to construct the `$traveler_info` array to use the structure acceptable to `db->batch_insert()`. It requires an associative array of field_names => field_values for each insert to be performed.

```
//add a sub-array to $traveler_info for each 'pass_type'
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['pass_type']); $i++)
{
    $traveler_info[] = array(
      `pass_type` => $_POST['pass_type'][$i],
      't_fname' => $_POST['t_fname'][$i],
      't_mname' => $_POST['t_mname'][$i],
      't_lname' => $_POST['t_lname'][$i],
      't_bday' => $_POST['t_bday'][$i],
      't_gender' => $_POST['t_gender'][$i],
    );
}
$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $traveler_info);
```